# Change TToolBar background color

Tags: delphi, common-controls

I got a problem, that I can't normally change the background color (e.g. `clwhite`) of `TToolBar` with its property `ToolBar.Color`. I'm not very experienced in Delphi and I find out two possible solutions, but still I'd like to know, how to change it proper way or why it's not possible.

1) Change style to Gradient, but it also changes the basic animations for buttons.

```
ToolBar.DrawingStyle := dsGradient
ToolBar.GradientStartColor := clWhite
ToolBar.GradientEndColor := clWhite
```

2) Put `TToolBar` inside `TPanel` with the following settings.

```
Panel.Color := clwhite
ToolBar.Parent := Panel
ToolBar.Align := alClient
ToolBar.Transparent := True
```

Comment: Is `ParentColor` false?

Comment: @LURD Sure, it sets automaticly to False when u change `Color` property.

Comment: Themed controls are, well, themed. You don't get to determine their colours. The theme does. If you don't like that, disable themes.

Comment: @LURD, `ParentColor` does not work on a TToolBar. The only reason it seems to work is because `Transparent = true` by default.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Themed doesn't mean, that you can't change its appearance at all, because there is always some workaround. I just don't understand purpose of `Color` property, if its useless, even if documentation says something different.

Comment: Nope. It's exactly as I said.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default a `TToolbar` ignores its `Color` property.
Also by default the `Transparent` property is `true`, therefore whatever the color of the Toolbar's parent is will shine through.

If you look at the VCL source code you'll see that TToolbar does not do its own drawing; it is a wrapper around the `ToolbarWindow32` Win32 common control in `ComCtl32.dll`.
This is the code that does the drawing.
When Windows XP was introduced Microsoft added UI themes and Borland supported this via [`VCL.Themes.TStyleManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager).
You can change the appearance of Common Controls through the style manager: `Project -> Options -> Appearance -> Custom Styles`, but its hard to know what effect this has, because the IDE does not display the result (you can see it at run time) and you can only choose from a limited list of rather odd themes; also the feature is buggy.

The same goes for `TPageControl/TTabSheet` which does not publish its Color propery.
All the controls imported via ComCtl32.dll and implemented by `VCL.ComCtrls` suffer from these inconsistencies.

**In short**
There is nothing you can do to make TToolbar respect its `Color` property.
You've already found the workarounds, either:

1. Set a gradient with identical `GradientEndColor` and `GradientStartColor`, or
2. Place the toolbar on another control (e.g. a TPanel) and change the color of that control, because the toolbar is transparent the parent color will shine through.
   You'll need to set the panel's `BevelInner`/`BevelOuter` to `bvNone`, or
3. Enable VCL styles and suffer all the issues related with that corporate tickbox anti-pattern.